# Decode phrases written using Greek letters in "Cloud Castles" by Michael Scott Rohan

Tags: translation

In Polish translation of "Cloud Castles" by Michael Scott Rohan, in chapter 6, translator missed phrases in English written using Greek letters.  I can decode some of them, could you please with deciphering the rest?

Written using [HTML 4.0 entities](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html):

- Βυγγερ οφφ

  *Bugger off*
- Γετ τηισ φαρτινγ χλοχxωορx ηαρπψ οφφ μψ φυχxινγ δεχx

  *Get this ??? deck*
- Γυεσσ τηε ωορδ Ι ωανθ ωιτη ψωυ

  *??? the ??? I want with you*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not too complex, he only uses omega both for w and o, psi for y and chi for c, which is not too fortunate. Yet there is an other reason too keep them coded...

- Βυγγερ οφφ

> Bugger off.

- Γετ τηισ φαρτινγ χλοχxωορx ηαρπψ οφφ μψ φυχxινγ δεχx <- translates to profanity

> Get this farting clockwork harpy off my fucking deck.

- Γυεσσ τηε ωορδ Ι ωανθ ωιτη ψωυ

> Guess the word I want with you.

Comment: I tried to use the spoiler tags, but they don't work great.  Feel free to roll it back or improve my edit.

Comment: @Mark Thanks, we have just made a simultaneous edit... I'll rollback to your version, it is better.

Comment: wow, that's was confusing for a second.

Comment: @Mark But I've earned two badges =)